# need code for search another character

Tags: javascript, regex

how to modify this code if i want search `JD` from `var str="KD-S35JWD"`..i try this but doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str = "KD-R435jwd";
var hasUD;
var hasJD;
var hasED;
var hasEED;
var patt1 = str.match(/U/gi);
var patt2 = str.match(/J/gi);
var patt3 = str.match(/E/gi);
var patt4 = str.match(/EE/gi);
var patt5 = str.match(/D/gi);

if (patt1 && patt5) {
    hasUD = 'UD';
    document.write(hasUD);
} else if (patt2 && patt5 {
    hasJD = 'JD';
    document.write(hasJD);
} else if (patt3 && patt5) {
    hasED = 'ED';
    document.write(hasED);
} else { 
       hasEED = 'EED';
        document.write(hasEED);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted code is correct, besides one points: In JavaScript, `elseif` should be `else if`.

If it possible that a string has both combination of characters, you may want to remove the `else` and have two `if`s:

```
if (patt1 && patt3) {
    hasUD = 'UD';
    alert(hasUD);
} 
if (patt2 && patt3) {
    hasJD = 'JD';
    alert(hasJD);
}
```

Another option is to use a more specific pattern. Currently you check for the characters **anywhere in the string**. For example, the `D` in `KD-` is enough to satisfy your condition. Depending on your *specification*:

1. D is always after U: `if(str.match(/U\w*D$/i))`
2. D is always last: `if(str.match(/U\w*D$/i))`
3. D and U are on the same block (any order): `if(str.match(/U\w*D|D\w*U/i))`

Another option is to use a single match for all cases:

```
var matches = str.match(/([JU])\w*(D)/i);
if(matches){
    var firstLetter = matches[1];
    var secondLetter = matches[2];
    alert(firstLetter + secondLetter);
}
else {
    alert(":(");
}
```

One last note: you don't need the `/g` flag in this case. The global flag is used to find all occurrences of the patters, but here you're only checking for one.

Comment: how if the condition like this:
i can show ED from KD-R435ED but if KD-R435EED i can't show EED..how to do this?

Comment: @klox - in that case, `matches[0]` is the whole match: `EED`. In the other cases it'd be `JWD` and `U2D`. If you want the *same character*, you can use `/([JU]\1*)\w*(D)/i` . You may want to edit your question to add these new requirements.

Comment: @klox - remember that if a string contains `EE`, it also contains `E`, so you should **check for EE first**. This will work for you, with my last code example: `/(EE|[EJU])\w*(D)/i`

Comment: ohh..must be separate,isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want them contiguous:

```
if(str.indexOf("UD") != -1)
{
  document.write("UD");
}
if(str.indexOf("JD") != -1)
{
  document.write("JD");
}
```

If anywhere counts:

```
var dInd = str.indexOf("D");
if(dInd != -1 && str.indexOf("U") != -1)
{
  document.write("UD");
}
if(dInd != -1 && str.indexOf("J") != -1)
{
  document.write("JD");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = "KD-R435jwd";
var matches = str.match(/(EE|[EJU])\w*(D)/i);
if(matches){
    var firstLetter = matches[1];
    var secondLetter = matches[2];
    alert(firstLetter + secondLetter);
}
else {
    alert(":(");
}

</script>
```

this the conclusion...